# Who has the biggest head?

Tags: overwatch

Every hero has a specific head hitbox that allows weapons to trigger as headshots on them.

Which heroes, from the biggest to the smallest, have the biggest head hitbox? In some ways I feel like D.VA has a huge head hitbox but at times it feels like Roadhog and Winston have bigger heads.

In all cases, who has the biggest head?

Comment: Relevant: https://youtu.be/_UU8jqxAiHQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D.va's mech has the biggest head as it's the entire cockpit area.

After that, I think it's Winston.

Having said that, as a general rule, the Tanks have bigger heads than the other characters.

Comment: Do you have a specific source for this? Or has it been tested that D.va has the biggest head hitbox?

Comment: Did... you really just ask me for a source of something that you can visibly see just by looking at the characters?

Comment: Wow, this is news to me, you can visibly see the size of their head hitboxes? It's one thing to look at their heads and take a guess which one is bigger, but it's another thing to show that the hitbox is actively bigger than another.

Comment: @Powerlord unfortunately, hitboxes and model sizes differ greatly. what we see in game bare only slight resemblance to the hit boxes of characters.. Imaging having to code collision detection for those models + projectiles in a team fight.. The lag would ruin the best of computers