# How can I view hitboxes in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Is there a way to view **hit/hurt boxes** of **characters / projectiles / environment objects** in Overwatch?

Much like in CS:GO where you can use a console command to view the hit boxes of player, I feel like this would be useful to see due to varied character model and projectile sizes.

Any insight into the hit boxes of Overwatch is appreciated.

Comment: I recently came across this article and figured it may be useful and/or interesting to you: http://kotaku.com/a-closer-look-at-overwatchs-generous-headshot-hitboxes-1780953233

Comment: Related, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UU8jqxAiHQ&feature=youtu.be from this Question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269162/who-has-the-biggest-head

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, since Overwatch does not contain a console similar to CS:GO or the like, there is no way to see character/environmental hitboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in the game so far, there's no way to actually "see" the hitboxes.  However, they certainly seem to cover the entirety of the characters, and possibly a little bit more.  I play Hanzo almost exclusively, and I've gotten some strange kills with him.  I've gotten a few kills by hitting people in their toes.  There was one, which I still don't exactly understand, where I wall climbed and fired a fully charged arrow downward when I got to the top.  I did not know there was anyone up there, but suddenly McCree went running by/near/under me, and he just died.  I almost didn't even know he was there until he dropped dead.  I wish I had a FRAPS recording of that to analyze it more, but I really didn't think I had hit him and suddenly I had.

Comment: This is a good start, but you might want to consider honing in on the hitboxes specifically... maybe you could create some graphics to describe what you've seen? What you've mentioned is good info, but some of it is more about playing Hanzo specifically than overall hitbox behavior.

Comment: @twobugs, Exactly as I thought. I haven't the time right now, but I plan on compiling images with visualised hitboxes around each character.